# Site security - no fields?

Tags: sitecore

I have setup a new user and roles to the Sitecore domain. The user should only have access to one of many branches, below the Content tree.

When i login with the user, it works - meaning i can only see the branch i have specified, i can create new items, delete etc. BUT - i cannot see any fields on the current item/template. Sitecore just displays "The current item does not contain any fields.". This is obviously not true, as there are plenty of fields on all items/templates.

First i though i also had to give explicit read access to the templates tree, but this did nothing. I have tried adding all the standard Sitecore roles, but nothing here helped either.
I also tried marking the user as an admin, just to test, and when i do this, everything shows up as it should. So i must me some missing security setting, but i cannot for the life of me figure out what it could be?

Comment: You've probably disabled access somewhere to one of the built-in Sitecore roles. Try to re-check the issue with clean installation and compare the Security Details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that for some wierd reason the sitecore\everyone role had read deny access to all the template fields. Not the template themselves, but only the fields. Wierd. Fixed by running a script and resetting security on the fields to standard values, and i works now.